Why does the bayestestR credible interval not accurately describe the posterior distribution of a beta distribution?
I'm attempting to calculate the 89% credible interval for a posterior distribution of an estimate of a proportion (and so the result is necessarily bounded by [0,1]) in R using the bayestestR package.
However when using the HDI() from the bayestestR library the result is CI low 5.15e-260 & CI high 1.09 (faint blue lines on the plot below).
ci_hdi <- distributionDF %>%
  filter(variable=="posterior") %>%
  select("Mechanism") %>%
  hdi(ci = 0.89, method="HDI")

(There are 1560 observations for this variable, so I haven't included the data here but see below for an MRE)
Prior, Likelihood and Posterior Distributions with CI:

I assumed I was making an error somewhere so I reproduced the example from the vignette, and got a similar result:
library(bayestestR)
library(ggplot2)
posterior <- distribution_beta(1000, 6, 2)

ci_hdi <- ci(posterior, method = "HDI")
ci_eti <- ci(posterior, method = "ETI")

output <- estimate_density(posterior, extend = TRUE)

ggplot(
  output, aes(x=x,y=y))+
    geom_area(fill = "yellow")+
    theme_classic()+
    #HDI in blue
    geom_vline(xintercept =ci_hdi$CI_low, colour = "royalblue", linewidth = 3)+
    geom_vline(xintercept =ci_hdi$CI_high, colour = "royalblue", linewidth = 3)+
    #ETI in red
    geom_vline(xintercept =ci_eti$CI_low, colour = "red", linewidth = 3)+
    geom_vline(xintercept =ci_eti$CI_high, colour = "red", linewidth = 3)

Resulting posterior distribution with CI:

Is this occurring because the densities (variable) are not normalised to one?

Can't reproduce: when I run the second example (from the vignette, with posterior correctly computed before the ci() statements, as I have now edited) I get a sensible plot.
